# What could be the problem with registerReceiver not working

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

While defining the receiver in the Manifest is working, I struggle with dynamic definition. My app contains this code for creating a broadcast

```
        val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
        val intent = Intent(this, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
        intent.setAction("com.example.PetesTimerOne.Broadcast")
        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, ALARM_REQUEST_CODE,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        alarmManager.setExact(
            AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
            firstAlarm.timeInMillis,
            pendingIntent
```

and for receiving I have a BoardcastReceiver class

```
package com.example.PetesTimerOne

import android.app.NotificationChannel
import android.app.NotificationManager
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.widget.Toast
import android.os.Build
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat
import androidx.core.app.NotificationManagerCompat
import androidx.core.content.getSystemService
import android.annotation.TargetApi

class AlarmReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = 100
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1000"
    }

    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onReceive called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        
        //createNotificationChannel(context)
        //notifyNotification(context)

        // println("onReceive called")
    }
```

If I define the receiver in the manifest via

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.PetesTimerOne.Broadcast"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

it IS working fine. However, when I try the dynamic defintion instead in my MainActivity

```
private val alarmReceiver = AlarmReceiver()
```

and in onCreate()

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    // alarm receiver
    val iF = IntentFilter(cBroadcastName)
    registerReceiver(alarmReceiver, iF)

    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)

    val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main)
    appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
    setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
}
```

it DOES NOT work, and I cannot figure why. I checked numerous tutorials and could not spot what I miss.

Comment: This will only work if your app is running when the alarm triggers. How are you testing this?

Comment: Thank you David, yes, app is running ofc. I start the app and start the alarm and the callback is never called (e.g. println produces no output, Toast does not pop up etc) , opposed to definition in the manifest XML which works like a charm.

Comment: Makes no sense. Your code looks fine. Please edit your question and post the code from `MainActivity.onCreate()` and also the code from `AlarmReceiver`.

Comment: Thanks David, added more of the code.

Comment: how is `cBroadcastName` defined?

Comment: Also, using `Toast` as a debugging technique is not reliable. You should add logging or set a breakpoint in the debugger

Comment: Thanks for helping David, a breakpoint in AlarmReceiver seems to never work, even when it _is_ called (and perfoming the actions within) the breakpoint didnt fire. I thought that might be you cant debug it for some reason. The constant is 

private val cBroadcastName =  "com.example.PetesTimerOne.Broadcast"

Comment: I'm running out of ideas. Try this: declare the member variable as `private lateinit var alarmReceiver : AlarmReceiver` and initialize it in `onCreate` like this: `alarmReceiver = AlarmReceiver()`. See if that helps. Are you doing anything else in the constructor of `AlarmReceiver`?

Comment: Nothing in constructor/init, no. I tried the lateinit as it looked like something that could make a difference, but unfortunately not. I now moved over to Handler/Looper and postDelayed which works and I give up on the Alarm stuff. Thanks so much for your help !!!

Comment: Not surprised. However, I don't understand why your code does not work. Sorry I cannot help.

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with same for hours. Finally got it to work.

Don't set the class in the intent, only set the action, so here:

> val intent = Intent(this,AlarmReceiver::class.java)

into

> val intent = Intent("com.example.PetesTimerOne.Broadcast")